# How to convert spring bean Oauth integration From XML to Java annotation based Config

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans, spring-java-config

I want to implement security for my Rest api and here what my question is, I have this xml based configuration. But in my project I want to use java annotation based configuration. How to convert xml based configuration to java based configuration? Below code is my xml based configuration, For all help thanks in advance.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
   xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- This is default url to get a token from OAuth -->
<sec:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
      authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>

<!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected and what roles have access to them -->
<sec:http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<sec:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>


<!-- This is simple authentication manager -->
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider>
        <sec:user-service>
            <sec:user name="arip" password="passw0rd" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </sec:user-service>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>


<!-- use in memory token store, this can be changed to a user defined one -->
<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<!-- token based configurations-->
<bean id="tokenServices"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="1000" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<!--client configuration-->
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client client-id="app"
                  authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials,password,refresh_token,implicit"
                  scope="read, write, trust"
                  secret="123456"/>
</oauth:client-details-service>

<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your xml configuration and import it in a java base configuration, like this :

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource(value="path/to/xml")
public class SecurityConfiguration{
  //additionnal configurations here
}
```

I think it's the best approach.

Comment: It would be best approach but my main moto is zero xml configuration application.

Comment: So you have to translate manually your xml into java. Each bean you declared in the xml has a class and may depend on other beans so follow the logic of your xml, using the same classes.

Comment: could you do conversion, because I am not very good at spring with oauth.